# Adding image into Pygoocanvas

Tags: python, gtk3

I have been trying to create a CanvasImage item in python using goocanvas however when I try to use the CanvasImage function it gives me an error.

```
pb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale("image2.jpg", 1920, 1080, True)
image = GooCanvas.CanvasImage(pb, 200, 200)
```

TypeError: GObject.**init**() takes exactly 0 arguments (3 given)

Am I missing something or am I using a wrong function to create an image on the canvas.
I am referring to this as there is no proper documentation for goocanvas bindings in python: https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/stable/GooCanvasImage.html

If Goocanvas is not suitable for python, please suggest a different canvas that I could integrate and use in python.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the call.
This is from the goocanvas github : https://github.com/GNOME/goocanvas/blob/33694b33cc337be86d8c848825a463e52bb1a2c0/bindings/python/demo.py#L190
Also the project's github states that it is no longer supported.

An actively developed and better documented library is PyGObject.
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

To display images: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Image.html#Gtk.Image